# "Следующий понедельник", "следующий четверг"

Tags: выбор-слова, словоупотребление, словоприменение

Согласно толковому словарю [Ушакова](http://www.onlinedics.ru/slovar/ushakov/s/sledujuschij.html), смысл слова "следующий":

> ближайший по очереди, первый из долженствующих появиться

Тем не менее, если мы говорим о днях недели, то мы скорее используем прилагательные "этот" и "следующий" в зависимости от того, подразумеваем ли мы день на этой неделе или на следующей. Например, если обсуждение происходит 21-го июля (во вторник):

> - Встретимся в следующий понедельник (имеется в виду 27-е июля, на следующей неделе)
> - Концерт будет в следующий четверг (имеется в виду 30-е  июля, на следующей неделе)
> - Приходи вечером, в этот четверг (имеется в виду 23-е июля, на этой неделе)

В последнем примере "четверг" как раз таки ближайший по очереди.  Это подходит под описание толкового словаря.  Но назвать его "следующим" кажется неестественным. Существует ли правило об использовании слова "следущий" применительно к дням недели?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Думаю, что "следующий" по отношению к дням недели мы применяем к наименованию дня не напрямую, а косвенно - через понятие "**следующая неделя**", которой этот день всецело принадлежит. Это связано с тем, что подсознательно мы и в прочих случаях не отмеряем время количеством четвергов или понедельников (в отличие от "количества недель"), а ориентируемся с помощью этих наименований только внутри недели. Строго говоря, для однозначности сначала нужно обозначить, на какой это неделе и только после этого - в какой день обозначенной недели. Выражение "следующий четверг" сокращённо выполняет именно эту функцию. Поэтому "**следующий четверг**" - это **четверг следущей недели** (той, которая начнётся по окончании текущей).

Слово "этот", однозначно относящее названный день к текущей неделе - необязательное уточнение: если мы говорим "в четверг" в явном контексте будущего (состоится то-то и пр.), то упомянутый четверг относится к текущей неделе. Можно сказать аналогично и о прошедшем событии текущей недели ("в четверг был дождь"). Контекст будущего делает иногда уместным и указание на день следующей недели без уточнения "следующий": в конце недели мы можем сказать, например, что "в понедельник я пойду к врачу", и это будет однозначно понято собеседником.

Понятие "ближайший четверг (понедельник)" характерно для ссылки на мероприятия, происходящие по расписанию в определённый день недели. Такая ссылка может косвенно указывать на "следующее" по очерёдности мероприятие, которое состоится на текущей, либо на следующей неделе - в зависимости от того, до или после четверга текущей недели это говорится (если в четверг, то нужно говорить "в следующий"). Кроме того, "ближайшим" четверг можно указать относительно какой-либо даты или события в будущем - в соотв. контексте (напр. "в ближайший к дате его приезда четверг он сможет попасть к этому врачу").

Comment: Хорошее объяснение, но мне не кажется, что *этот* *однозначно* относится к текущей неделе. При отсутствии других привязок - да. Но вообще указательные местоимения сильно зависят от контекста. Например, *«в этот понедельник я пойду к врачу»* наверняка относится к следующей неделе, а не к  текущей. А «*в это воскресенье был ливень*» - к

Comment: Не согласен! Тогда выходит, что понедельник текущей недели тоже "этот", даже если он прошел? И во вторник я могу сказать: "Я в этот понедельник не работал. А вот в прошлый (имея в виду понедельник предыдущей недели) я трудился." Так не логично!

Answer (score 0):

Формального  правила об использовании слова "следующий" применительно к дням недели я не знаю, и не знаю, существует ли оно. Но мы говорим о днях недели так, как Вы написали. Ближайший четверг мы называем "этот четверг"; четверг, который будет через четверг, мы называем "следующий четверг". А составители словарей своими формулировками меня тоже иногда сбивают с толку.

Formal rules about the use of the word "next" in relation to the days of the week I don't know and don't know it is there. But we're talking about days of the week as You wrote. Next Thursday we called "this Thursday"; Thursday, which will be after Thursday, we call "next Thursday". But the compilers of dictionaries and their wording me too sometimes confusing.

Comment: Он говорит по-другому, вы даже вопрос неправильно прочитали.

Comment: Он перемудрил с цифрами, расчётами арифметическими. Я не стал заниматься предлагаемыми автором вопроса подсчётами дней, поэтому действительно его не понял. Насчёт следующего понедельника 27 июля автор вопроса неправ. В России бы в этом случае сказали (чтобы не возникло путаницы) "встретимся в ближайший понедельник", "встретимся 27-го июля, в понедельник" или "встретимся на следующей неделе, в понедельник".

Comment: "В следующий понедельник, вторник или четверг" может быть не всеми правильно понято. Если в пятницу сказать "встречаемся в следующий понедельник", могут переспросить "в ближайший или через неделю?" Слово "следующий" в отношении дней недели сейчас уже не воспринимается в соответствии с толкованием словаря Ушакова. Лучше употреблять слово "в ближайший понедельник", "в этот понедельник" или просто "в понедельник."

Answer (score 0):

В этот понедельник ,я работал -прошедшее время !
В этот понедельник ,я пойду к врачу- будущее время ! Если я это говорю во вторник , что этот понедельник я пойду к врачу, я подразумеваю ближайший понедельник (будущее время) т.у. на следующей неделе. Я понимаю так и это логично.